# Forcing ArcMap to display HTML pop-ups for just one layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, arcgis-10.5, html-popup

At 10.5.1, I have an .mxd that contains several polygon feature class layers.  I have created an HTML pop-up (my first-ever!) for one of those layers.  Let's call that layer "A".

The pop-up works great, in that it points to the correct url.

But there's a problem: when I click on a feature, the resulting pop-up displays data concerning the other layers - not the desired layer "A". I can force layer "A" to pop-up only if I turn off the display for **all** the other layers, leaving only layer "A" checked on in the TOC.

Turning the other layers on and off is awkward and time-consuming.  How do I specify that the pop-up tool only apply to layer "A" in the TOC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Setting HTML pop-up properties for feature layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/setting-html-pop-up-properties-for-feature-layers.htm) you should only see HTML Popups on layers for which you:

> Check the **Show content for this layer using the HTML Popup tool** check box

on the HTML Popup tab of the Layer Properties.

If it is checked on for layer "A" and off for all other layers, then you should be able to achieve your required functionality of having multiple layers displayed but HTML Popups only enabled for layer "A".